# Customize the paginator component of angular material according to my requirements

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, mat-table

In my application, there is a component in which populates the rows using angular material table.
Since Server Side pagination is implemented and json response is given below.

`list` - object which contains table records.
`next`, `first`, `last`, `previous` - These object links which will give the next/first/previous/last page data.

I need to assign the values of `next`, `first`, `last`, `previous` to angular material pagination buttons.

[image: Material Pagination <code>showFirstLastButtons</code>]

Is there any way to customize the pagination buttons?
Please provide me some suggestions.

JSON response:

```
{  
list: [],  
totalRecords: 100,  
message: "Patient search successfull",  
next: "http://localhost:8084/findPatient/?page=2&size=10&patientId=&patientFirstName=&patientLastName=",  
first: "http://localhost:8084/findPatient/?page=0&size=10&patientId=&patientFirstName=&patientLastName=",  
last: "http://localhost:8084/findPatient/?page=9&size=10&patientId=&patientFirstName=&patientLastName=",  
previous: "http://localhost:8084/findPatient/?page=0&size=10&patientId=&patientFirstName=&patientLastName=",  
size: 10,  
currentPage: 1
}
```

Web Application built using Angular 7 and Spring Boot. Since I am new to Angular, I don't know create custom directive for pagination.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `PageEvent` to control the paginator behaviour

```
<mat-paginator [length]="length"
              [pageSize]="pageSize"
              [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
              (page)="onPageEvent($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```

```
onPageEvent(event: PageEvent) {
   this.yourService.loadData(event.pageIndex).....;
}
```